WordPress website Phantom wallet, user account creation plus payment
I’m creating a website specifically WordPress. I need to know if there is a plug-in or some type of code etc.
I want users to come to my website and create account using a Phantom wallet. Also, I want users to purchase my service for one Solana with that Phantom wallet under a username.
User should be able to log back into their account using the Phantom wallet where they can see previous orders in purchased my service again.
Is there a WordPress plug-In or some type of code, etc.?
Thank you
